# Foxpro SELECT query cant find item is case isnt correct

Tags: foxpro

I have a table with a CustomerName field. I have a record where the CustomerName is 'CustomerABC' my select query is as follows:

```
   SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
from CustomersTable
WHERE CustomerName='CustomerABC'
```

This returns the record but if the case is wrong, it returns nothing. e.g.

```
    SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
from CustomersTable
WHERE CustomerName='customerabc'
```

would produce no results.

Surely, users aren't expected to know the correct case of the record they are searching for!? Could someone help me with this please?

Thanks
John

Comment: Just realised that if I force the string being sent to be converted to uppercase then I can use this.. WHERE UPPER(CustomerName)='CUSTOMERABC'

Comment: seems long-winded just for this simple job - is this normal for foxpro?

Comment: Yes, this is normal for VFP. Data is case-sensitive, so if you want to do a case-insensitive search, you have to code it.

Comment: No they're not, which is why you index on UPPER(customername), and use UPPER(searchterm) in your queries. Thus case is removed as a factor, and your queries will be Rushmore-optimised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default FoxPro's `=` and `==` operators are case sensitive so this will impact queries.  However, the command `SET COLLATE TO "GENERAL"` can be used to change the behavior and will allow upper/lowercase characters to match in comparison operations.

If you want to use the default and ignore case, then use either UPPER() or LOWER() functions to convert the strings for comparison.  If the query will be executed in code (vs an ad hoc query in the command window) it is usually a good idea to apply the functions to both sides of the comparison unless you know for sure that the data in the table is formatted a certain way.

```
SELECT fieldA, fieldB, fieldC
from CustomersTable
WHERE UPPER(CustomerName)=UPPER('customerabc')
```

Also when using string comparisons, consider the impact of the `SET EXACT` and `SET ANSI` settings as they control the behavior for padded strings and strings of different length.

Comment: It's important to note that using COLLATE set to "GENERAL" has some consequences. First, it means an index key can be only 120 characters, not 240. Second, you can lose Rushmore optimization with collation sequences other than "MACHINE". On the whole, it's better to use UPPER() for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes use ...

```
ALLTRIM(UPPER(CustomerName)) == UPPER('customerabc')
```

... OR if I'm trying to match a variable or another field I will use ...

```
ALLTRIM(UPPER(CustomerName)) == ALLTRIM(UPPER(SomeOtherField))
```

... just to be sure I get my exact matches.

Comment: Be aware that wrapping with ALLTRIM() can interfere with optimization. Rushmore only works when one side of the comparison exactly matches an existing index tag.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your replies, as it seems like I've chosen a sensible option. In the UPPER choice (and my queries are still very fast) I think I'll stick with this). Glad it's been confirmed that this is how foxpro works

Thanks again
John